# Ionic 2/3 Plugin loading Issue: possibly from app.bundle.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, ionic-framework

Okay so I've hit an uncanny problem with my Ionic framework project. I've been working at this error for a day and a half with no results aside from knowing what the problem *might* be.

My nativeGeocoder, facebookLogin, and googleLogin plugins are not working at all.

However, my Camera plugin, and Geolocation plugin works.

I get the following errors from Ionic serve to browser:

```
The resource from “http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Which means that for some reason, my **app.bundle.js** is not generating when I build. I am assuming that this may be the primary cause of the problem, but I also get a few other errors on browser as well.

```
Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator  main.js:45448:9
Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

Which seems to tell me to run the code on a device, however, this doesn't quite explain why geolocation works on browser despite it being a cordova plugin, and when I run the code on an android device, and use the android debug mode to grab logs, I get this error from the android device.

**android device:**

```
I/chromium( 5892): [INFO:CONSOLE(45432)] "Native: tried calling NativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode, but the NativeGeocoder plugin is not installed.", source: file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js (45432)
D/SystemWebChromeClient( 5892): file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js: Line 45438 : Install the NativeGeocoder plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder'
I/chromium( 5892): [INFO:CONSOLE(45438)] "Install the NativeGeocoder plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder'", source: file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js (45438)


D/SystemWebChromeClient( 5892): file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js: Line 45432 : Native: tried calling Facebook.login, but the Facebook plugin is not installed.
I/chromium( 5892): [INFO:CONSOLE(45432)] "Native: tried calling Facebook.login, but the Facebook plugin is not installed.", source: file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js (45432)
D/SystemWebChromeClient( 5892): file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js: Line 45438 : Install the Facebook plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4'
I/chromium( 5892): [INFO:CONSOLE(45438)] "Install the Facebook plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4'", source: file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js (45438)
D/SystemWebChromeClient( 5892): file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js: Line 45357 : Error logging into Facebook

I/chromium( 5892): [INFO:CONSOLE(45432)] "Native: tried calling GooglePlus.login, but the GooglePlus plugin is not installed.", source: file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js (45432)
D/SystemWebChromeClient( 5892): file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js: Line 45438 : Install the GooglePlus plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus'
I/chromium( 5892): [INFO:CONSOLE(45438)] "Install the GooglePlus plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus'", source: file:///data/data/com.ionic.viewapp/files/files//4715e941/build/main.js (45438)
```

Again noting, the camera and geolocation plugins from Cordova work, while these plugins are not even detected by the device.

Is this because of the bundle.js error? Are plugins recognized through that file? I thought it was all processed through cordova.js.

The steps I took for debugging this were the following:

**1.** tried uninstalling plugins I've had installed but didn't use. Also going into package.json to delete their calls.

**2.** tried reordering plugin order in config.xml

**3.** uninstalled and reinstall geocoding plugin.

**4.** generally tried having as few plugins loading up as possible to try to rule out *any* possible plugin conflicts.

None of these solutions have worked for me, and bundle.js is still not generating, which, to my guess, may be the cause for the problems.

The problem appears to come from either the config.xml, package.json, or index.html I will post the code that I have for all three of these files.

My **index.html** loads like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <!-- Polyfill needed for platforms without Promise and Collection support -->
 <!-- The bundle which is built from the app's source code -->
 <script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My **package.json** loads up like this:

```
{
    "name": "projname",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^3.10.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^3.10.2",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.10.3",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.10.3",
        "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^3.10.3",
        "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^3.10.3",
        "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.10.2",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.10.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.6.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.0",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-image-picker": "^1.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^1.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.2.1",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.3.0",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "keywords": "^0.1.2",
        "rxjs": "5.1.1",
        "sass": "^0.5.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.2.1",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.2.0",
        "typescript": "2.3.3"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {},
            "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {},
            "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
                "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "myreversedclientid"
            },
            "keywords": [
                "latitude",
                "longitude",
                "city",
                "location",
                "geo",
                "latlon",
                "position"
            ],
            "cordova-plugin-image-picker": {},
            "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
                "APP_ID": "166628403873954",
                "APP_NAME": "projname"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android",
            "ios"
        ]
    }
}
```

My **config.xml** loads up like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.projname.id" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.4.0" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="keywords" spec="^0.1.2">
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-image-picker" spec="^1.1.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder" spec="^1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^1.9.0">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="166628403873954" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="projname" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="^5.1.1">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="myreversedclientid" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Any possible solutions here? Is there are least any way I could "reset" my config/package files and plugins back to default when I first generated the project? Is there anything wrong with how my index.html is loaded?

Is there any explanation as to why some plugins may load while others won't?

Thanks! Any feedback is highly appreciated, I really want to continue making progress on this project.

EDIT: Here's my **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { IdentifymytickPage } from '../pages/identifymytick/identifymytick';
import { IdguidePage } from '../pages/idguide/idguide';
import { RemovalPage } from '../pages/removal/removal';
import { SymptomsPage } from '../pages/symptoms/symptoms';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { AmericandogtickPage } from '../pages/pushpages/americandogtick/americandogtick';
import { BrowndogtickPage } from '../pages/pushpages/browndogtick/browndogtick';
import { DeertickPage } from '../pages/pushpages/deertick/deertick';
import { GenderPage } from '../pages/pushpages/gender/gender';
import { LifestagesPage } from '../pages/pushpages/lifestages/lifestages';
import { LonestartickPage } from '../pages/pushpages/lonestartick/lonestartick';
import { WesternblackleggedtickPage } from '../pages/pushpages/westernblackleggedtick/westernblackleggedtick';


import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import { NativeGeocoder } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder';
import { LocationAccuracy } from '@ionic-native/location-accuracy';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    IdentifymytickPage,
    IdguidePage,
    RemovalPage,
    SymptomsPage,
    LoginPage,
    AmericandogtickPage,
    BrowndogtickPage,
    DeertickPage,
    GenderPage,
    LifestagesPage,
    LonestartickPage,
    WesternblackleggedtickPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    IdentifymytickPage,
    IdguidePage,
    RemovalPage,
    SymptomsPage,
    LoginPage,
    AmericandogtickPage,
    BrowndogtickPage,
    DeertickPage,
    GenderPage,
    LifestagesPage,
    LonestartickPage,
    WesternblackleggedtickPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Camera,
    GooglePlus,
    ImagePicker,
    Facebook,
    NativeGeocoder,
    LocationAccuracy,
    Geolocation,


    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Geocoding Code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { IdentifymytickPage } from '../identifymytick/identifymytick';
import { IdguidePage } from '../idguide/idguide';
import { RemovalPage } from '../removal/removal';
import { SymptomsPage } from '../symptoms/symptoms';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { LocationAccuracy } from '@ionic-native/location-accuracy';
import { NativeGeocoder, NativeGeocoderReverseResult, NativeGeocoderForwardResult } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder';




@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public geolocation: Geolocation, public nativeGeocoder: NativeGeocoder, public locac: LocationAccuracy) {

    this.watch();

  }

  nextPage()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(IdentifymytickPage)
  }

  nextPage1()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(IdguidePage)
  }

  nextPage2()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage)
  }

  nextPage3()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(RemovalPage)
  }

  nextPage4()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(SymptomsPage)
  }






coords:any;
accuracy:any;
error:any;

watch() {
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    this.coords = resp.coords.latitude + ' ' + resp.coords.longitude;
    this.accuracy = resp.coords.accuracy + ' meters';
  }).catch((error) => {
    this.error = 'Error getting location: ' + error;
  })
}


//
// townvar:any;
//
// nearestCity() {
//
//   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
//     this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude)
//       .then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult) => this.townvar = result.city)
//       .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
//   })
//
// }

// geolocate() {
//   let options = {
//     enableHighAccuracy: true
//   };
//
//     this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((position: Geoposition) => {
//     this.getcountry(position);
//
//   }).catch((err) => {
//     console.error(err);
//   })
//
// }
//
// getcountry(pos) {
//   this.geocoder.reverseGeocode(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude).then((res: NativeGeocoderReverseResult) => {
//     console.log(res.countryName, res.city, res.district)
//
//   })
// }

geolocateTEST() {

  this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(52.5072095, 13.1452818)
    .then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult) => console.log('The address is ' + result.street + ' in ' + result.countryCode))
    .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));

  this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode('Berlin')
    .then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult) => console.log('The coordinates are latitude=' + coordinates.latitude + ' and longitude=' + coordinates.longitude))
    .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just from your index.html - and it concerns the Content-Security-Policy....
Just follow the direction below. It will just take a simple step.

> From your root folder > src > index.html

change this line of code

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ms-appdata: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Your index.html should look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ms-appdata: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">


  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunately it didn't help. I'm running into the same errors. The only thing I noticed is that the code made the geolocation plugin throw a location error but that's about it.

Comment: is there a way i could see your app.module.ts

Comment: I just edited the main post with my app.module.ts. If you could look at it, that would be a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: If u just migrated your app, then you would need to run both ionic and npm installs for each of your native plugins... E.g $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation   and   $ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation

Comment: Please, try to install the latest ionic CLI 3 http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-cli-v3/   ... It is so user friendly and will help us easily detect and install the missing pieces

Comment: I don't think I migrated it to 3. However, I uninstalled and reinstalled all of my plugins, and even launched a new project and added some plugins and it's throwing me the same errors. Could it have something to do with ionic native/ionic itself? Or should I just disregard these errors? I found that bundle.js wasn't even needed in my project as it was deprecated, so that got rid of the critical error message at least.

Comment: Ok. Great. did you install your plugins with both ionic and npm commands... like this -> E.g $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation and $ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation

Comment: Yup. My installations were done correctly, so that rules that out. My geolocation and camera plugin works (but also throw out similar errors when run in browser) but my big issue is that the geocoding plugin is still not working and I am not sure why. I will edit in my geocoding script.

Comment: OK. Also note that native plugins are not meant to work on browsers but are adapted to work on your phone when installed with it's apk.

Comment: That's really good to know. Someone else clarified that to me as well. My geocode is edited into the original post. Thanks c:

Comment: If I have given you a well considered help, you can consider marking my post as an answer.